# When did Phineas and Ferb meet Dr. Doofenshmirtz?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb, milo-murphys-law

In the *Milo Murphy's Law* episode *The Phineas and Ferb Effect*, (Season 2 Episode 1), Dr. Doofenshmirtz and Phineas see each other and mention that they've met before.

> **Doofenshmirtz**: Hey, the pizza delivery kid!
> **Phineas**: Ferb, look! It's Vanessa's dad! You remember him!

Ferb and Doofenshmirtz did meet in [*Across the 2nd Dimension*](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Phineas_and_Ferb_the_Movie:_Across_the_2nd_Dimension), but their memories were erased afterwards, so they must have met again at some point.

When did Phineas and Ferb meet Dr. Doofenshmirtz? And why does Doofenshmirtz call Phineas a pizza delivery kid?

Comment: https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/The_Phineas_and_Ferb_Effect mentions that “Phineas and Ferb interact with Doofenshmirtz for the third time. ("Phineas and Ferb The Movie: Across the Second Dimension", "Night of the Living Pharmacists")”.  But I haven't watched the Living Pharmacists for a long time so I don't recall the details.  I can't recall what the pizza delivery kid refers to: Candace was disguised as a pizza delivery boy in the season 4 episode “Mandace”, but that doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phineas and Ferb and Dr. Doofenshmirtz meet briefly and exchange words while fighting off a horde of Doof-zombies in [Night of the Living Pharmacists](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Night_of_the_Living_Pharmacists).

> Vanessa: Dad! (runs up to him for a hug) It's you! Okay, so what did
> you do?
>
> Doofenshmirtz: Well, it was just a simple Repulse-inator, y'know to,
> to make Roger ugly, but then, there was some sort of power surge and
> this happened!
>
> Phineas: (tinkering with the inator) Well, that explains the
> electromagnetic charge that's changing everybody. But we need some
> kind of conductor that neutralizes it.
>
> Isabella: Well, water neutralizes static.
>
> Phineas: Yes! Water should change everyone back!
>
> Vanessa: Um, isn't that a bit of a leap?
>
> Doofenshmirtz: No, I'm a scientist. I'm gonna go with 'im on that. I
> might have a water pistol lying around. I-I can go get it.
>
> Phineas: Yeah, but we've gotta find a way to get everyone in Danville
> wet at once. Otherwise, the contagion could start again.

Re the pizza delivery kid comment--I think this may have been referring to Milo, rather than Phineas. Doofenshmirtz had mistaken him for a pizza delivery kid earlier in the episode.

> Doofenshmirtz: So... in a nutshell, what you're saying is, you're not
> the pizza delivery guy.
>
> Milo: No, we are not the pizza delivery guy.

And the more of the quote you've posted:

> Milo: Time to bail!
>
> Cavendish: Milo! Grab my hand!
>
> Doofenshmirtz: Hey, the pizza delivery kid!